# WebClient stuck

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to ask you why my WebClient stops after around 10 results?
Here's code.

```
foreach (var player in game["fellowPlayers"])
{
    WebClient webC = new WebClient();
    TextBlock playerName = new TextBlock();
    playerName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 205, 3));
    Thickness playerMargin = playerName.Margin;
    if (player["teamId"].ToString() == teamId)
    {
        playerMargin.Top = 180 + (30 * teamRedIndex);
        playerMargin.Left = 150;
        teamRedIndex++;
    } else
    {
        playerMargin.Top = 150 + (30 * teamBlueIndex);
        playerMargin.Left = 300;
        teamBlueIndex++;
    }
    playerName.Margin = playerMargin;
    matchGrid.Children.Add(playerName);

    webC.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(playerLoad);
    loadPlayer(webC, player["summonerId"].ToString(), playerName);
}
```

I'm trying to get ~50 results (i mean `game["fellowPlayers"]`'s count is ~50).

Comment: It feels like a spaghetti , that function is doing too much .

Comment: How about adding some try catch and also keeping fiddler open to see what network calls are happening